# XCode + Phonegap + Sencha Can I deploy to other platforms?

Tags: xcode, cordova, extjs, multiplatform

I have to start work on phone gap. Till now i have found out that Sencha is a good way for developing ui thus i have chosen to use Phonegap + Sencha. I came to know that i can export the "www" folder to eclipse to deploy the app on android if I use Phonegap. So my question is, will I still be able to deploy it on android if I also use Sencha with Phonegap?? If so, how? I am following this url for developing in iOS:

> http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use phone gap build service for any platform like

1) Android 
2) iphone
 and many more

for android in eclipse you will get the .apk file

for using phoneGap build service (which is free) you can get .apk file

[phone gap build service](https://build.phonegap.com/)

Comment: if somehow i don't have to use phoneGap build.. can i still port it to others??

Comment: means, eclipse should have phone gap as well as sencha library included in it, right?